# How to implement multiple joins with sqlalchemy relationships

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy

I have a (for most of you) simple problem with sqlAlchemy and Python. I have four tables with 1-to-N relation, and I want to join this tables.
I marked my problems with a #?????? in my example code.

Has anybody an idea how I can implement the '#??????' ? Thank you!

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    allMy_B = relationship("B")
    allMy_C = # ??????
    allMy_D = # ??????

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "b"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    my_A_parent = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("a.id"))
    allMy_C = relationship("C")
    allMy_D = # ??????

class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = "c"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    my_B_parent = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("b.id"))
    allMy_D = relationship("D")

class D(Base):
    __tablename__ = "d"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    my_C_parent = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("c.id"))
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a partial answer:  For the first, blank, you can use a secondaryjoi table:

```
allMy_C =relationship(C, secondary = B)
```

For d, though, you'll need to create a selectable that joins B and C, and I don't remember off the top of my head how to do that.  So I'm marking this as a community wiki question and someone can edit to fill in the rest.